# Align drop-down ul lists at the same height at the top of the drop-down navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I work with drop-down menu and I have one issue. When I open the drop-down menu, ul list belonging to li element that I clicked on appears at the same height as the li element, but I want to align that ul list with previous ul list so the ul list that will open on the right side will be at the top of the drop-down navigation.

Hope you understand. I attached 2 images below the post. At the first image is the current drop-down how it usually works and the second image represents the result that I want to achieve.

Thank you for your help

[Old drop-down navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC9vh.png)

[New drop-down navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWcwB.png)

Comment: Could you post your code? As without code, it's really hard to help

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .dropdown-submenu {
     }
.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0px;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    position:absolute;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

By the way this is not a problem this how it works :)